# VueJS Unknown Component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this code on the mounted hook

I'm using a component from `Synfusion` and I've initialize it in the mounted hook like so :

```
data() {
          return {
              treeViewInstance: {},
          };
      },
 mounted() {
    var data = [
        {
            nodeId: '01', nodeText: 'Music',
            nodeChild: [
                { nodeId: '01-01', nodeText: 'Gouttes.mp3' }
            ]
        },
        {
            nodeId: '02', nodeText: 'Videos', expanded: true,
            nodeChild: [
                { nodeId: '02-01', nodeText: 'Naturals.mp4' },
                { nodeId: '02-02', nodeText: 'Wild.mpeg' },
            ]
        },
        {
            nodeId: '03', nodeText: 'Documents',
            nodeChild: [
                { nodeId: '03-01', nodeText: 'Environment Pollution.docx' },
                { nodeId: '03-02', nodeText: 'Global Water, Sanitation, & Hygiene.docx' },
                { nodeId: '03-03', nodeText: 'Global Warming.ppt' },
                { nodeId: '03-04', nodeText: 'Social Network.pdf' },
                { nodeId: '03-05', nodeText: 'Youth Empowerment.pdf' },
            ]
        },
    ];
    //Initialize TreeView component
    var treeViewInstance = new ej.navigations.TreeView({
        fields: { dataSource: data, id: 'nodeId', text: 'nodeText', child: 'nodeChild' },
        allowDragAndDrop: true,
    });
                this.treeViewInstance = treeViewInstance;
                console.log(treeViewInstance);

    //Render initialized TreeView
treeViewInstance.appendTo("#tree");
```

The problem is that the `treeViewInstance` in data properties have a weird value `Unknown Component`

[image: DevTools Screenshot]

I don't know what to do to get the `treeViewInstance` in the `data`

Answer (score 0):

Your component needs to be registered:
[Component Registration](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration)

Something like this:

```
components:
{
    my-component: myComponent
},
```

Comment: What if I have tried registering the component locally and globally even in main.js and it still appears this way?